# Java Script for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

I want the loop to run until the value of prompt but it's going infinite.
Need help. Here is my javascript code:
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTOp7.png)

```
var round = prompt("enter text");
var roundno = round;

var images_arr = ["../img/paper.png", "../img/stone.png", "../img/sisor.png"];
var size = images_arr.length
function myFunction() {
for (var i = 0; i = roundno; i + 1) {
    console.log(i);
    setInterval(function () {
        var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
        $('#random').attr('src', images_arr[x]);
    }, 1500);

    setInterval(function () {
        var sound = new Audio("../audio/audio.mp3");
        sound.play();
    }, 3000);

    if (i = roundno) {
        break;
     }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

```
var round = prompt("enter text"); // how do you know the user enters a number?
var defaultNumberOfRounds = 1;  // I added this row

// CHANGED THIS IN EDIT 
var roundno = round; // should be: isNaN(Number(round)) ? defaultNumberOfRounds : round

var images_arr = ["../img/paper.png", "../img/stone.png", "../img/sisor.png"];
var size = images_arr.length
function myFunction() {

// CHANGED THIS IN EDIT the conditions within () should be: var i = 0; i < roundno; i++
for (var i = 0; i = roundno; i + 1) {
    console.log(i);

    // all iterations in the loop will execute this at the same time.
    setInterval(function () {
        var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
        $('#random').attr('src', images_arr[x]); // JQuery
    }, 1500);

    // all iterations in the loop will execute this at the same time.
    setInterval(function () {
        var sound = new Audio("../audio/audio.mp3");
        sound.play();
    }, 3000);

    if (i = roundno) { // should be i == roundno
        break; // don't need to break it, because your for loop's condition should take care of this
     }
    }
  }
} // ADDED THIS IN EDIT: missing curly bracket
```

[edit] I added a snippet to show that my code is working. I commented all code within the for loop, and I had to change declaring `roundno` and the statement within the for loop.

```js
var round = prompt("enter text");
var defaultNumberOfRounds = 1;
var roundno = isNaN(Number(round)) ? defaultNumberOfRounds : round;
var images_arr = ["../img/paper.png", "../img/stone.png", "../img/sisor.png"];
var size = images_arr.length;
console.log(`round: ${round}, roundno: ${roundno}`);
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < roundno; i++) {
    console.log(i);

    /*setInterval(function () {
        var x = Math.floor(size * Math.random())
        $('#random').attr('src', images_arr[x]); // JQuery
    }, 1500);

    setInterval(function () {
        var sound = new Audio("../audio/audio.mp3");
        sound.play();
    }, 3000);*/

  }
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: I have tried doing all those changes but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I made a mistake, and also discovered a missing bracket. I change part of the code and also made a snippet.

Comment: Thank you so very much for helping me out with this. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not incrementing `i`

Change

```
i + 1
```

to one of the following:

- `i++`
- `i += 1`
- `i = i + 1`

Also you need to fix the `if` statement at the end of the loop. You want to check whether `i` is equal to `roundno` or not. Instead of using assignment operator `=` which will assign the value of `roundno` to `i`, use `==` or `===` for equality check.

```
if (i == roundno) {
   break;
}
```

You have made the same typo in loop condition as well. Change loop condition to `i == roundno` and remove the `if` statement at the end of the loop because with loop condition fixed, `if` statement inside the loop is unnecessary.

```
for (var i = 0; i == roundno; i++) {
   // code
}
```

Comment: For completeness... `i = i + 1` will also suffice, additionally there's a typo later on where the OP is assigning `i` to a new value.  The condition later should be: `if (i == roundno)`.  **Edit:** The condition *within* the loop definition should *also* be `i == roundno`.